# Java program skipping while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I am having a problem with my while loop. It is compiling but it isn't entering while loop and it skips to next condition.

```
public class Tr {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = "";

        while(name.length() > 1) {     
            System.out.print("Enter  name : ");
            name = in.nextLine( );  
            if(name.length() > 1) {
                System.out.println("It needs to be greater than  1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: u can use   while(name.length() == 0)
        {     
           System.out.print("Enter  name : ");
           name = in.nextLine( );  
           if(name.length() > 1)
           {
              System.out.println("It needs to be greater than  1");
           }

        }

Comment: If i dont enter it it will print me error:
variable name might not have been initialized

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `name` has 0 length and hence, the control never enters `while`. You need to use `do..while` loop so that it executes at least once, e.g.:

```
do{     
   System.out.print("Enter  name : ");
   name = in.nextLine( );  
   if(name.length() <= 1){
        System.out.println("It needs to be greater than  1");
   }
}while(name.length() <= 1);
```

Comment: Probably need to make those `>` into `<` but using a `do ... while` is the right answer.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon updated the answer, thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the logic you want is to prompt the user for a name, and keep prompting until a name with length greater than one is entered.  A `do` loop would seem to fit well here:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;

do {   
    System.out.print("Enter name with length > 1: ");
    name = in.nextLine();
    // you can print an optional feedback message
    if (name.length() <= 1) {
        System.out.println("length needs to be greater than 1");
    }
} while (name.length() <= 1);
```

Comment: No it still skips it if you press enter. I need to find if the user enters name smaller than 1 it will send him error message and he will need to input name again.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `name` gets initialized to `name = "";`, so `name.length() == 0;`.

Your while condition checks whether the length greater than 1, and it isn't so it skips.

Comment: yes but i need to initialize it or it will not work. Sry i am new to programing so i dont know alot.

Comment: I know you do, but your while loop is practically the same as `while(false)`. Change the `>` in your while and if condition to `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `name.length()` always returns 0 so your condition won't ever be true.

Answer (score 0):

(name.length() < 1) 
change this condition in our while and if conditions.

You have defined an empty string called name and the condition for your while loop condition checks if the length of name is greater than 1 or not.

Comment: yes but i need to initialize it or it will not work. Sry i am new to programing so i dont know alot.  I just need to user not to input name smaler than 1